# How can I set my background Image to automatically resize with window size?

Tags: css, javafx, background, uiimageview

My `.fxml file` consists of an `AnchorPane` + an `ImageView` which is the background. I tried the CSS commands

```
backgroundImage.setStyle("-fx-background-position: left top, center;");
backgroundImage.setStyle("-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;");
backgroundImage.setStyle("-fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
```

where `backgroundImage` is the `fx:id` of the `ImageView`. But whatever I do, the Image stays the same size resulting in white bars when I resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `auto` from `-fx-background-size`.
 `auto` means - Default value. The background-image contains its width and height

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It stays the same size. What I could imagine is, that because I'm using a separat ImageView the CSS commands have no impact because the ImageView doesn't get the information about the current window size. Do I need a Listener for that or should I set the image directly as the AnchorPane backgroundImage with `-fx-background-image + url`?